# Menu closing after going to the related section from the hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, hamburger-menu

Good encodings for everyone,

When I click the relevant place in the hamburger menu, it goes in the background but the menu does not close. How do I make this menu close when I click the relevant place?
Menu related code:

```css
 #header .hamburger {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(.8);
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#header .hamburger:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid white;
    animation: hamburger_puls 1s ease infinite;
}
#header .hamburger .bar {
    height: 2px;
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: -1;
}
#header .hamburger .bar::after,
#header .hamburger .bar::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    transition: .3s ease;
    transition-property: top, bottom;
}
#header .hamburger .bar::after {
    top: 8px;
}
#header .hamburger .bar::before {
    bottom: 8px;
}
#header .hamburger.active .bar::before {
    bottom: 0;
}
#header .hamburger.active .bar::after {
    top: 0;
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: Your code snippet is empty

Comment: where is the html part of this, and no javascript ??

Comment: In JavaScript you need to add a class to the menu when you click on a link, and that class has CSS styles that hide the menu